# Как автоматически запускать звуки в браузере?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, браузер, firefox

Подскажите кто сталкивался. У меня задача такая. Мне нужно сделать автоматическое проигрывание звуков firefox. Как это можно включить? Проект на React. Работа звуков в других браузерах мне не очень интересна

Comment: каких именно звуков? о чём речь?

Comment: Сразу при открытии сайта никак, если об этом речь. Это ограничения с точки зрения безопасности.

Answer (score 0):

В firefox нужно ставить настройки, которые позволяют проигрывать аудио и видео при загрузке страницы автоматически

Comment: Будешь пользователей всех обязывать это делать?))